# Pick the smallest or highest number in accordance with another column

Tags: python, pandas

One column in a data frame has names, each name is repeated at least 10 times so there are many names.
In another column, I have numbers.
I want to add two new columns, one displaying the lowest number for a specific name (that appears in the NUMBERS column), and the second displaying the highest number.

This is a dummy data that is similar to my real data, just to make my question more clear :

[image]

Comment: Post the data as text and your expected output.

Comment: The picture I added is kind of the output I need, each name has a lowest or highest value. @Ynjxsjmh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['a','b','a','b','b','c','a','c'],
                   'val':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]})
```

Using `groupby`, `transform` and `apply`:

```
df['min'] = df.groupby('name')[['val']].transform(lambda g: g.min())
df['max'] = df.groupby('name')[['val']].transform(lambda g: g.max())
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can try

```py
out = df.merge(df.groupby('Names')['NUMBERS']
               .agg(**{'Lowest Number': 'min', 'Highest Number': 'max'}).reset_index())
```